# Trying to use Animate.css pulse but its not working

Tags: css, css-animations, animate.css

I trying to use the pulse feature from Animate.css on my gallery photos but it won't work.

I used the Animate.css CDN 
 - `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.css" />`

then I added the `class="pulse"` to my `img` but nothing happened. Is there another step I'm missing.

Comment: Did you miss adding `animated` class?

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the Github page's `README.md` file (their [front page](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css)). They outline 3 steps for basic usage.

1. Include the stylesheet.
2. Add the class `animated` to it.
3. Add the effect you'd like to use (listed in a table on that same page).

Hope that helps!

(Directly referring to your question, I suggest trying `class="animated pulse"` rather than what you currently have)